# Cannot connect to Azure MySQL from Laravel app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, azure

I have a Laravel App that is using MySQL as its main DB. We are now trying to implement the Azure MySQL service, but the usernames comes with an '@' in it.

For example, if my server name is "test", then to connect from cli:

`mysql -htest.mysql.database.azure.com -u'someuser@test' -p`

I can connect from Java and Go with no problem, but Laravel can't handle the '@' in the username. It takes the string after '@' as the host and tries to connect to it, but it doesn't resolve to any IP, so the connection fails.

I have tried to escape the sign like 'user\@test', '`user@test`' and 'userU+0040test', but nothing works. The server always returns this error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [9002] The connection string may not be right. Please visit portal for references`

The Azure portal shows the code to connect using `mysqli`, and that works, but I cannot use that from Laravel (I think?).

How could I make this connection work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using double qoutes around your username. Like
e.g  "someuser@test"